# C++ custom list implementing push_back and pop_front

Tags: c++, list

I am hoping someone can help me. I'm struggling to correctly implement the `push_back` and `pop_front` methods for a custom list I'm making. When I run my main program it freezes and windows reports it stops working. This list is being used to build a queue. I have already made my queue class and tested it with the stl list (for my assignment I need to make a custom list as well) so I am fairly certain the problem lies in my list. I think I have not coded push_back and pop_front correctly. Sorry if this is a dumb question, I tried searching for cases similar to mine but I couldn't find any. I would appreciate any help.

my node classs

```
template<typename T>
class cNode{
   public:
     T nodeVal;
     cNode<T> *next;
     cNode<T> *prev;
     cNode<T>();
     cNode<T>(const T& v, cNode<T> *n, cNode<T> *p);
};

//Methods
//defualt constructor
template<typename T>
cNode<T>::cNode(){
};
//constructor with value value next and prev
template<typename T>
cNode<T>::cNode(const T& v, cNode<T> *n=NULL, cNode<T> *p=NULL){
   nodeVal=v;
   next=n;
   prev=p;
};
```

and my list, I commented out the other methods because they are not being using is the queue class

```
#include "cNode.h"
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class cList{
    private:
        cNode<T> *frontNode;
        cNode<T> *backNode;
        int sizeOfList;
    public:
        cList();
        bool empty();
    //  void push_front(const T& val);
        void push_back(const T& val);
        void pop_front();
    //  void pop_back();
        T front();
    //  T back();
        int size();
};
//Methods
//Constructor
template <typename T>
cList<T>::cList(){
    frontNode = NULL;
    backNode = NULL;
};
//Returns true if empty
template<typename T>
bool cList<T>:: empty(){
    return frontNode == NULL;
};

//Adds to the back of the list
template<typename T>
void cList<T>:: push_back(const T& val){
    cNode<T> *newNode; 
    newNode = new cNode<T>;
    newNode->nodeVal=val;
    //inserting in place
    newNode->prev = backNode->prev;
    newNode->next = backNode;
    backNode->prev->next = newNode;
    backNode->prev = newNode;
    //update size
    sizeOfList++;
};
//Removes from the front of the list
template<typename T>
void cList<T>:: pop_front(){
    cNode<T> *df;
    df = new cNode<T>;
    df = frontNode;

    df->next->prev=df->prev;
    frontNode=frontNode->next;
    delete df;
    //update size
    sizeOfList--;
};
//Returns value of of the front
template<typename T>
T cList<T>:: front(){
    return frontNode->nodeVal;
};
//Returns the size of the list
template<typename T>
int cList<T>:: size(){
    return sizeOfList;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What is spotted right after looking at your code,
you init `backNode` and `frontNode` with NULL value,
but after that in `push_back` you use `operator->` for them,
you need allocate memory for them, before usage.

Little modification of your algorithm to make it works:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>

template <typename T> struct cNode {
  T nodeVal;
  cNode<T> *next;
  cNode<T> *prev;

  cNode<T>(const T &v = T(), cNode<T> *n = NULL, cNode<T> *p = NULL)
      : nodeVal(v), next(n), prev(p) {}
};

template <typename T> class cList {
private:
  cNode<T> head_;
  size_t sizeOfList_;
  typedef cNode<T> NT;

public:
  cList() : sizeOfList_(0) {
    head_.next = &head_;
    head_.prev = &head_;
  }
  ~cList() {
    for (NT *p = begin(); p != end();) {
      NT *next = p->next;
      delete p;
      p = next;
    }
  }
  cNode<T> *cbegin() const { return head_.next; }
  cNode<T> *begin() { return head_.next; }
  cNode<T> *end() { return &head_; }
  bool empty() const { return head_.next == &head_; }

  void push_back(const T &val) {
    NT *newNode = new NT(val);
    NT *prev_end = end()->prev;
    prev_end->next = newNode;
    newNode->prev = prev_end;
    newNode->next = end();
    end()->prev = newNode;
    ++sizeOfList_;
  }

  void pop_front() {
    if (empty())
      return;
    NT *next_in_list = begin()->next;
    NT *prev_in_list = begin()->prev;
    delete begin();
    head_.next = next_in_list;
    if (prev_in_list == end())
      end()->prev = end();
    --sizeOfList_;
  }
  T front() const {
    assert(!empty());
    return cbegin()->nodeVal;
  }
  size_t size() const { return sizeOfList_; }
};

int main() {
  cList<int> l;
  assert(l.size() == 0);
  assert(l.empty());
  l.push_back(10);
  assert(!l.empty());
  assert(l.size() == 1);
  assert(l.front() == 10);
  l.pop_front();
  assert(l.size() == 0);
  assert(l.empty());

  for (int i = 5; i < 17; ++i)
    l.push_back(i);
  assert(l.size() == (17 - 5));
  assert(l.front() == 5);
  assert(!l.empty());
  {
    cNode<int> *p;
    int i;
    for (p = l.begin(), i = 5; p != l.end(); p = p->next, ++i) {
      assert(p->nodeVal == i);
    }
    assert(i == 17);
  }
  l.pop_front();
  assert(l.size() == (17 - 5 - 1));
  assert(l.front() == 6);
  assert(!l.empty());

  l.pop_front();
  assert(l.size() == (17 - 5 - 2));
  assert(l.front() == 7);
  assert(!l.empty());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will find a diagram very useful here - drawing out pointers is one way to be absolutely sure what is referencing what.

That said, here are a few things that jump out:

- you initialize `frontNode` and `backNode` to `NULL` in the constructor. What will happen when you try to dereference these `NULL`s during your very first `push_back` operation?
- related: what value will `frontNode` have *after* a single `push_back` operation? And what value **should** it have?
- what will happen if you try to pop an item off of an empty list?
- at each end of the list, the end node should have one of `prev` and `next` be `NULL` or another value indicating that they point nowhere.

The main points here are that you've got a lot of `NULL`s being dereferenced and you're not updating everything you need to be. The way to wrap your head around the problem is to make a diagram with arrows and boxes and walk through, step by step, what needs to happen when you start with an empty list, add two or three nodes to it, and then successively pop them off.